# How do I set up a vps myself?

Tags: vps

And is it linux only?

I'm using windows

Comment: How about some more details... What is your goal?

Comment: can you update the question to be more clear and have more detail?  otherwise, im tempted to mark you down.

Answer (score 5):

That's a pretty broad question, but we can give you the basics of what you need to do.  If you can provide a bit more detail on what exactly you're looking to accomplish we can give you some better information.

It's not just for Linux, you can certainly virtualize Windows.

1. Get yourself some virtualization software and install it on your host system.  Examples are [**VirtualBox**](http://www.virtualbox.org/), [**VMWare**](http://www.vmware.com), and [**Hyper-V**](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/hyperv.aspx) if you're using Windows 2008.
2. Set up a virtual machine through the virtualization software following the instructions of whatever you're using
3. Install an OS on the new virtual machine.  Note that you must have the installation media and proper licensing to do this.

Again, though, that's a VERY simplistic explanation.  There is a considerable amount of things you need to think of in order to do this properly, especially if you are planning on using a VPS in any kind of production environment.

Alternatively, you can find a plethora of VPS hosts out on the Internet if you don't want to do it yourself.

Comment: Can you recommend some virtualization software for windows/linux?

Comment: I did.  See Item 1 in my answer.

Comment: FYI both Hyper-V is free and VMWare ESXi? or one of their product offerings is also free. That still doesn't alleviate the need for licensing each guest os.

Comment: Wow. Gotta give you some points for even trying to answer this question.